# Ionic build : Error: spawn EACCES

Tags: android, macos, ionic-framework

I face an error while building `android apk with Ionic`,I tried to set the `folder security access` on the folder to everyone with `read & writer`, but still failed. The error as below.

> Yees-MacBook-Pro:OneMesa e-qi$ ionic build android
>   Running command: /Users/e-qi/Desktop/OneMesa/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /Users/e-qi/Desktop/OneMesa
>
> add to body class: platform-android
>
> Running command: /Users/e-qi/Desktop/OneMesa/hooks/after_prepare/020_remove_sass_from_platforms.js /Users/e-qi/Desktop/OneMesa
>
> ANDROID_HOME=/Users/e-qi/Library/Android/sdk
>
> JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home
>
> Error: spawn EACCES

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo ionic build android
```

Then it should work.

On the other side you can set the access rights of different folders. Be sure that you set the access rights  recursively to all subfolders and files. The different paths you find inside the error message.

I face the same issue. Every time when i add a platform i have to set the access rights again. I don't know why.